# Positioning a js button under the content it affects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a button which on click expands the div and shows some content. I want it to be positioned at the bottom of the div permanently, same as it is now positioned at the top, but to be down under. I struggle because it affects the event so i can't just move it within the parent div.

```js
 $('button, .smallx').click(function(){
  let box = $(this).closest('.container').find('.content');
  if ( box.hasClass('collapsed') ){
    box.removeClass('collapsed');
  }else{
    box.addClass('collapsed');
  }
});
```

```css
.collapsible {
  border: none;
    width: 60px;
}

.container{max-width:800px;margin-bottom:20px;overflow:hidden;}
.collapsed{max-height:65px;max-width:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content collapsed">
     <button class="collapsible">More</button>
    <div>Mauris dui mi, faucibus a elit id, bibendum euismod elit. Aenean pharetra laoreet quam in laoreet. Etiam interdum ligula ac gravida laoreet. Sed tempor lacus mauris, ac feugiat felis viverra eget. Donec dignissim, lacus nec congue interdum, nisl arcu pharetra sapien, id porttitor arcu odio non lectus. Aliquam pulvinar urna quis pretium facilisis. Ut elementum rutrum quam. In tincidunt dui non felis convallis, quis dictum ligula dictum. Vestibulum enim lorem, auctor a iaculis at, mattis ut leo. Sed volutpat venenatis finibus. Cras sapien mauris, ultricies vel facilisis in, pharetra sit amet lacus. Curabitur quis faucibus nibh, vestibulum rhoncus magna. Pellentesque faucibus magna sed molestie aliquam. Nullam convallis auctor diam, et rhoncus erat faucibus sit amet. Nulla quis pulvinar augue.
  </div> </div></div>
```

Comment: So what is the question? Note you can replace the `if()` with `box.toggleClass('collapsed')`

Comment: How to put the button underneath it all, so it is not on top

Comment: You mean move it with jQuery?

Comment: i want it to be permanently, by default, at the bottom of the container div

Comment: What's wrong with simply moving `<button />` under your `<div />`?

Comment: it wont work anymore (expanding the div) if you just move it in code @DimitriKopriwa

Comment: I've tried and it seemed to work straight

Comment: hello @erutuf  plz check my answer to see if thats what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place the button after the div content collapsed and give the div text overflow:hidden; not the container

```js
$('button, .smallx').click(function(){
  let box = $(this).closest('.container').find('.content');
  if ( box.hasClass('collapsed') ){
    box.removeClass('collapsed');
  }else{
    box.addClass('collapsed');
  }
});
```

```css
.collapsible {
  border: none;
    width: 60px;
}

.container{max-width:800px;margin-bottom:20px;}
.collapsed{max-height:65px;max-width:200px;overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content collapsed">
     
    <div>Mauris dui mi, faucibus a elit id, bibendum euismod elit. Aenean pharetra laoreet quam in laoreet. Etiam interdum ligula ac gravida laoreet. Sed tempor lacus mauris, ac feugiat felis viverra eget. Donec dignissim, lacus nec congue interdum, nisl arcu pharetra sapien, id porttitor arcu odio non lectus. Aliquam pulvinar urna quis pretium facilisis. Ut elementum rutrum quam. In tincidunt dui non felis convallis, quis dictum ligula dictum. Vestibulum enim lorem, auctor a iaculis at, mattis ut leo. Sed volutpat venenatis finibus. Cras sapien mauris, ultricies vel facilisis in, pharetra sit amet lacus. Curabitur quis faucibus nibh, vestibulum rhoncus magna. Pellentesque faucibus magna sed molestie aliquam. Nullam convallis auctor diam, et rhoncus erat faucibus sit amet. Nulla quis pulvinar augue.
  </div> </div><button class="collapsible">More</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **css way**

```js
$('button, .smallx').click(function(){
  let box = $(this).closest('.container').find('.content');
  if ( box.hasClass('collapsed') ){
    box.removeClass('collapsed');
  }else{
    box.addClass('collapsed');
  }
});
```

```css
.collapsible {
  border: none;
    width: 60px;
}
.content{
position:relative;
}
button{
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
right:0px;
}

.container{max-width:800px;margin-bottom:20px;overflow:hidden;}
.collapsed{max-height:65px;max-width:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content collapsed">
     <button class="collapsible">More</button>
    <div>Mauris dui mi, faucibus a elit id, bibendum euismod elit. Aenean pharetra laoreet quam in laoreet. Etiam interdum ligula ac gravida laoreet. Sed tempor lacus mauris, ac feugiat felis viverra eget. Donec dignissim, lacus nec congue interdum, nisl arcu pharetra sapien, id porttitor arcu odio non lectus. Aliquam pulvinar urna quis pretium facilisis. Ut elementum rutrum quam. In tincidunt dui non felis convallis, quis dictum ligula dictum. Vestibulum enim lorem, auctor a iaculis at, mattis ut leo. Sed volutpat venenatis finibus. Cras sapien mauris, ultricies vel facilisis in, pharetra sit amet lacus. Curabitur quis faucibus nibh, vestibulum rhoncus magna. Pellentesque faucibus magna sed molestie aliquam. Nullam convallis auctor diam, et rhoncus erat faucibus sit amet. Nulla quis pulvinar augue.
  </div> </div></div>
```

Is this what you want?

> **HTML BLOCK WAY**

```js
$('button, .smallx').click(function(){
  let box = $(this).closest('.container').find('.content');
  if ( box.hasClass('collapsed') ){
    box.removeClass('collapsed');
  }else{
    box.addClass('collapsed');
  }
});
```

```css
.collapsible {
  border: none;
    width: 60px;
}
.content{
position:relative;
}
button{
}

.container div{max-width:800px;margin-bottom:20px;overflow:hidden;}
.collapsed div{max-height:65px;max-width:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content collapsed">     
    <div>Mauris dui mi, faucibus a elit id, bibendum euismod elit. Aenean pharetra laoreet quam in laoreet. Etiam interdum ligula ac gravida laoreet. Sed tempor lacus mauris, ac feugiat felis viverra eget. Donec dignissim, lacus nec congue interdum, nisl arcu pharetra sapien, id porttitor arcu odio non lectus. Aliquam pulvinar urna quis pretium facilisis. Ut elementum rutrum quam. In tincidunt dui non felis convallis, quis dictum ligula dictum. Vestibulum enim lorem, auctor a iaculis at, mattis ut leo. Sed volutpat venenatis finibus. Cras sapien mauris, ultricies vel facilisis in, pharetra sit amet lacus. Curabitur quis faucibus nibh, vestibulum rhoncus magna. Pellentesque faucibus magna sed molestie aliquam. Nullam convallis auctor diam, et rhoncus erat faucibus sit amet. Nulla quis pulvinar augue.
  </div> </div><button class="collapsible">More</button></div>
```

Comment: i am trying to avoid absolute and relative positions since it doesn't work properly if you have more elements

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this

```
  if ( box.hasClass('collapsed') ){
    box.removeClass('collapsed');
  }else{
    box.addClass('collapsed');
  }
```

**for**

```
box.classList.toggle('collapsed')
```

Comment: that is not what he ask

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want the button to sit right under the box/container that it will be toggling the visibility for. You should be able to do that using just css. Something like

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content collapsed">
    <div class="text">Mauris dui mio</div>
    <button class="collapsible">More</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

moved the button under the content and added a class to the div

```
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}

.collapsible {
  border: none;
  width: 60px;
}
```

plus the rest of your styles. Then you can have the click function on the button and have the div with `.text` change height with some logic to check the current height. Also using position absolute could do this as well with something like

```
.content {
  position: relative;
}

.collapsible {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100;
}
```

I believe its bottom 100. Either that or bottom 0